# Extract created_by_user and modified_by_user from users table

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I want to extract created_by_user and modified_by_user from users table at the same time so can some body please tell me what query should i write to get both created by user and modified by user name which can also be different in the single table

I am working on php codeignitor.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that `SELECT created_by_user, modified_by_user FROM your_tab`

Comment: i have two tables one is of the users and other of the news in the news table for the created by and modified by column the userid is placed.Now for showing the details of the news i also want created by and modified by user name by joining both news and users table